# GOOGLE SHEETS - How do i copy a checkbox value and keep the cell editable?

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

This is my first post, and I'd like to preface that I'm not a programmer: I know some Excel and Google Sheets formulas, and that's it.
Here's my problem. In a Google Sheets page, I have some checkbox values that I need to copy to another set of checkboxes in another page in the same file. The problem is that I need to keep the  receiving checkboxes editable, while Google Sheets doesn't allow me this.
Basically, what I've done is: in a cell in page 2 (the receiving one) I've inserted a checkbox, and then added a formula to that cell to copy the corrisponding value from a checkbox in page 1 (the starting one):

=page1!A1

With this formula, the receiving checkbox copies the value from the starting one, but becomes uneditable (= I can't manually change the value of that checkbox), while I need it to remain editable. It's not a problem to lose the formula, but I need the receiving checkbox to remain editable.
Is there a way around this problem without complicated codes or macros? Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, sheets, data, data types, etc.; and we don't know your end goal. So while what you are describing may seem clear to you, for those of us "out here," it is not at all clear. I suggest that you share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), illustrating there what you are trying to do.

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Erik Tyler, here's the link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TCQ0cWulb8Wm63Hs57ruwEXgpP1swKAi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110569351169109673921&rtpof=true&sd=true
Basically, as I've programmed the file right now, when I check a checkbox in the page "pianificazione", it copies the value in the page "effettivo", rendering the receiving cell uneditabile (you can see that because in the page "effettivo" the checkboxes can't be manually ticked). My question is then: how do I copy the checkboxes value from "pianificazione" to "effettivo" while mantaining the checkboxes editable?